# JS RAILS API Delete Button

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a RAILS API with a JavaScript vanilla front end. I am trying to create a delete button to erase content. I'm getting stuck on it rendering the request. If needed I can share the repository.

I'm just trying to have the delete button that is rendered when a new content card gets put in delete the entry itself. I can't seem to figure this out.

World JavaScript to render the button upon creation of item.

```
display() {

  // display post details in a card in the post-lists   
  let deleteBtn = document.createElement('button')
  deleteBtn.setAttribute('class', 'delete-world-btn')
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'Remove'
  deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', event => this.deleteWorld(event, this))
  document.getElementsByClassName("character-lists")[0].innerHTML += this.template();
}

deleteWorlds() {
  event.preventDefault()
  fetch(`${deleteUrl}/${this.id}`, {
    method: "DELETE"
  }).then(() => { 
    document.getElementById(`${this.id}`).remove()
    World.all = World.all.filter(world => world.id !== this.id)
  })
}
```

Index.js - DOM

```
function addClickEventToPostListHeader() {
  document.querySelector('.character-lists h3').addEventListener('click', changeColor);
}

function addSubmitEventToForm() {
  document.getElementById("character-form").addEventListener('submit', Api.submitWorld);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  // We have access to all of the DOM elements
  addSubmitEventToForm();
  Api.getWorlds();
});
```

```html
<div class="input-field">
  <input type="text" name="planet" id="planet">
  <label for="planet">Where is your home planet?</label>
</div>
<label for="content">Home Planet Information</label>
<div class="input-field">
  <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="50"></textarea>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Create Character" class="btn">
</div>
```

I'd really just love for the delete button to delete the individual content entries.

Comment: what is your html structure?

Comment: <div class="input-field">
                    <input type="text" name="planet" id="planet">
                    <label for="planet">Where is your home planet?</label>
            </div>

            <label for="content">Home Planet Information</label>
            <div class="input-field">
                  <textarea name="content" id="content" cols="30" rows="50"></textarea>
            </div>
            
            <input type="submit" value="Create Character" class="btn">
            
        </div>

Comment: It seems there is no relationship between the html snippet you added and the delete operation. Please paste full context.